# Install packages from internet for VPC with no outside access

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, amazon-vpc, anaconda

Have a `VPC` with a private subnet. Inside the `VPC`, am looking to update latest 
`Anaconda` packages using `Conda` which involves downloading the latest updates from internet. Since my VPC has no internet access, what is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest approach would be to add an internet gateway, create a new Public subnet with a default (0.0.0.0/0) route to the internet via the new internet gateway. Then deploy a NAT gateway into the new public subnet. Then update the route table on your private subnet with a default route via the NAT Gateway.

If you want more control over what access to the internet your private instance has (e.g. limit it to only be able to reach a specific package repository), you can either restrict it's outbound security group (although this can be a pain to manage) or substitute the NAT Gateway service for a NAT instance with a restricted security group or for your own proxy where you can apply more granular rules - however in both cases these don't have the native HA capability of the NAT gateway, although for simply package updates that might not be a concern.